# Button with image - images disappear

Tags: c, button, gtk

That's my very first post here. First of all I'd like to apologise for my poor english. I really hope you will understand what I try to say.

Ok, so there's my problem: I have a few buttons generated in loop:

```
int board = 4;
int board_2 = board*board;
GtkWidget *card_button[board_2];

char path[100];
sprintf(path,"res/0.png"); //path to default image
GtkWidget *button_image = gtk_image_new_from_file(path);

for(int i=0; i<board_2; i++)
{
    card_button[i] = gtk_button_new();
    gtk_button_set_image(card_button[i],button_image);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),card_button[i],i%board,(i/board)+1,1,1);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(card_button[i]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(game_engine), i);
}
```

game_engine function:

```
void game_engine(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    int button_id = (int)data;
    char path[30];
    sprintf(path,"res/%d.png",button_id);
    GtkWidget *button_image = gtk_image_new_from_file(path);
    gtk_button_set_image(widget, button_image);
}
```

When I click the button, everything seems to be ok (image shows on the button), but sometimes, besides showing image on clicked button, another image disappears. Moreover GTK shows following error on console:

```
(Program.exe:4920): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I did some debbuging and found that this error is caused by gtk_button_set_image in game_engine function. I don't know what to do next.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the value of `i` at the point of `GtkWidget *card_button[i];`? I guess the `i` should be `board_2`.

Comment: You're right - that's a typo. In my source files I have it declared correctly as `GtkWidget *card_button[board_2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution. To avoid losing images I had to use `g_object_ref(button_image);`
So there's correct code:

```
void game_engine(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{        
    int button_id = (int)data;
    char path[30];
    sprintf(path,"res/%d.png",field[button_id].val);
    GtkWidget *button_image = gtk_image_new_from_file(path);
    g_object_ref(button_image);
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(widget),button_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So on your line

```
     gtk_button_set_image(widget, button_image);
```

you are using a GtkWidget* widget, but gtk_button_set_image expects:

```
    void gtk_button_set_image (GtkButton *button, GtkWidget *image);
```

so you could try to cast it (GtkButton should be below widget in hierachy)

```
    gtk_button_set_image((GtkButton *)widget, button_image);
```

or hand it over as a button instead of a GtkWidget.
Your error message just tells you, that you are using the wrong type

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't help. I noticed, that terminal error message doesen't show up when image disappear...

Comment: Is it always the same image, that disappears or is it a random one?

Comment: Well... The image always disappears on button I clicked right before the next which "caused" disappearing. In example: I clicked buttons 1, 2, 3, 4 and image dissapeared after I clicked 4 => disappeared image on button 3. I also noticed that image dissapear every 6 clicked buttons.

Comment: If you use gprints to show id and path, are they set correct?
in general increase you degub output... maybe the error will show up.

Comment: Path and id are set correct. I also put some other variables on terminal for debbuging, and every value is ok. I'm going to compile my code in linux environment. I doubt, but maybe there's problem with Windows itself.